# xsl finding relative position to ancestor node

Tags: xml, xslt, position, relative-path, ancestor

Have some problems to get the position of childs `division` relative to the `section` node. Here is my XML file:

```
<document>
    <section>
        <division>text of division</division>
        <division>text of division</division>
        <division>text of division</division>
    </section>
    <section>
        <division>text of division</division>
        <division>text of division</division>
        <division>text of division</division>
    </section>
</document>
```

And here is my XSL:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:for-each select="//section">
       <div class="section">
           <xsl:text>section </xsl:text>
           <xsl:value-of select="position ()"/>
           <xsl:apply-templates/>
       </div>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="division">
    <div class="division">
        <xsl:text>division </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select='count(../preceding-sibling::section)+1' /><xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="position ()"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

And I would like this kind of output where the position depend to `section`:

```
section 1
division 1.1 
division 1.2
division 1.3
section 2
division 2.1
division 2.2
division 2.3
```

And not this one:

```
section 1
division 1.2 
division 1.4
division 1.6
section 2
division 2.2
division 2.4
division 2.6
```

It seems to be something like `../section[position()]` or `../ancestor/position()` but it's wrong… Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `position()`, try using `xsl:number` instead.

Example:

**XML Input**

```
<document>
    <section>
        <division>text of division</division>
        <division>text of division</division>
        <division>text of division</division>
    </section>
    <section>
        <division>text of division</division>
        <division>text of division</division>
        <division>text of division</division>
    </section>
</document>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

    <xsl:template match="section|division">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(),' ')"/>
        <xsl:number level="multiple" count="section|division"/>
        <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
section 1
division 1.1
division 1.2
division 1.3
section 2
division 2.1
division 2.2
division 2.3
```

---

EDIT: Here's another example that's closer to what you were doing in your XSLT. (I added `<p>` elements to wrap the text though.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="text()"/>

    <xsl:template match="section|division">
        <div class="{name()}">
            <p>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(name(),' ')"/>
                <xsl:number level="multiple" count="section|division"/>             
            </p>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>              
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<div class="section">
   <p>section 1</p>
   <div class="division">
      <p>division 1.1</p>
   </div>
   <div class="division">
      <p>division 1.2</p>
   </div>
   <div class="division">
      <p>division 1.3</p>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="section">
   <p>section 2</p>
   <div class="division">
      <p>division 2.1</p>
   </div>
   <div class="division">
      <p>division 2.2</p>
   </div>
   <div class="division">
      <p>division 2.3</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh thanks a lot, it working! Just another question related to this one. If I have many `<p>` in the xml nodes `<division>`, something like that:    `<document>
    <section>
        <division><p>text</p><p>text</p></division>
        <division><p>text</p></division>
        <division><p>text</p></division>
    </section>
    <section>
        <division><p>text</p></division>
        <division><p>text</p><p>text</p></division>
        <division><p>text</p><p>text</p><p>text</p></division>
    </section>
</document>`  How can I number all the <p> from the document and not from the division?

Comment: Sorry, have found `<xsl:number level="any"/>`. Thanks once again !