# XML Node position

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, position

How do I get relative position of a node in a given XML. Say I have below xml, I want to know first b node in second a is position 3.

```
<a>
    <b></b>
    <b></b>
</a>
<a>
    <b></b>
    <b></b>
</a>


<xsl:for-each select="a">
            <dummy>
            <xsl:for-each select="b">
                <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
                <dummy2><xsl:value-of select="$pos"/></dummy2>
            </xsl:for-each>
           </dummmy>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I expect dummy2 to have 1,2,3,4 values.

```
<dummy>
    <dummy2>1<dummy2>
    <dummy2>2<dummy2>
</dummmy>
<dummy>
    <dummy2>3<dummy2>
    <dummy2>4<dummy2>
</dummmy>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xsl finding relative position to ancestor node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16719736/xsl-finding-relative-position-to-ancestor-node)

Comment: @bated - I would like the sequence to continue in my case. One you referred does not suggest a way to do it

Comment: The answer you need is hidden anyway in comments in the answer to the question. Try doing `<xsl:number level="any" />` instead of `<xsl:value-of select="$pos"/>`

Comment: @TimC thanks, it worked. How do I get distinct count of values from the result? count(dummy/dummy2[not(.=preceding-sibling::*)] does not work

Comment: XSLT works on the input tree, not the output tree. It's probably best you ask a new question here.

Answer (score 0):

For checking with current result, you need to assign all conversion in a variable like

```
    <xsl:variable name="Data">
    <xsl:for-each select="a">
        <dummy>
            <xsl:for-each select="b">
                <dummy2><xsl:number level="any"/></dummy2>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </dummy>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>
```

After that you can easily interpret your query in result data

```
    <xsl:value-of select="count($Data//dummy/dummy2[not(.=preceding-sibling::*)])"></xsl:value-of>
```